# Adding exclusive filter for <static initializer> in findbugs

Tags: java, groovy, findbugs

I want my findbugs report not show the following error:

**DM_NUMBER_CTOR: Method invokes inefficient Number constructor; use static valueOf instead**

The problem is that this happens in groovy-generated code files, so I can't control the source code - that is why I want to exclude it and add it to my exclude filter.

I do not want to add explicitly class (since I make API that many tools will use, I want my filter to be generic). I would not like to completely remove this bug from the report by type, I would really like to only exclude this bug from appearing if it happenned in "static initializer" methods. Any idea? I tried the filter below but no luck, maybe somebody has better idea?

```
<Match>
    <Method name="~.*static initializer.*" />
    <Bug pattern="DM_NUMBER_CTOR" />
</Match>
```

Here is the "stacktrace" of FindBugs in that case:

*In class net.milanaleksic.cuc.tools.sound.SoundPlayerTool
In method net.milanaleksic.cuc.tools.sound.SoundPlayerTool.()
Called method new Long(long)
Should call Long.valueOf(long) instead
In SoundPlayerTool.groovy*

Comment: Why have you tagged this 'groovy', does FindBugs work on Groovy code? I know you can probably run it on groovy classes, but are the results actually useful?

Comment: it is still too early too say, but I think that with some time ivested in it you can do good things find findbugs. I target folder with compiled Java & Groovy files (I used groovyc task), so basically I do findbugs processing of both Java and groovy-generated bytecode.
You can see example of filtering out AspectJ compiled bytecode as a similar case on next page: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html#d0e2050

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would **guess** the static initializer code would be reported as taking place in method called `<clinit>`. Could you try setting a `<Method name='&lt;clinit&gt;'/>` filter? (which is pretty much `<clinit>` but XML-escaped). Totally untested, just some random thoughts.

My clue was this part of http://findbugs\.googlecode\.com&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc&l=125">some FindBugs internal tests:

```
 String methodName = m.getMethodName();
 ...
 if (...  methodName.equals("<clinit>")) ) ...
```

I am not sure but I think the same method name (`<clinit>`) is mentioned if the bugs actually happen...

Comment: Thanks! I confirm that following filter really does what I wanted:
    <Match>
        <Method name="&lt;clinit&gt;" /> 
        <Bug pattern="DM_NUMBER_CTOR" />
    </Match>

Comment: I have filed an issue report in FindBugs bug tracker: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3000303&group_id=96405&atid=614693 So we can hope they will explain this hidden feature in their docs.

Comment: <clinit> is the internal class file format name for a static block, as <init> is the internal name for a constructor.